# Hollow Cylinder vs Solid Cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

Thanks to angular momentum, we know that hollow cylinders are slower than solid cylinders when rolled down an inclined plane - Is this difference in speed (or time taken to get to the bottom of the incline) noticeable with a full and empty can of deodorant?

Is there any factor that would determine whether this difference would be noticeable (such as length of incline, angle of incline, etc.)?

How could variables be changed so that this difference is noticeable?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Calculating_moment_of_inertia_about_an_axis, in particular the animated graphic. Your comparison is only valid when comparing cylinders of *equal radius and equal mass*. But when a cylinder is filled with *liquid (or gas)*, instead of a solid, the calculation changes. If the liquid or gas is *inviscid* it will contribute nothing to the moment of inertia of the whole can. Virtually no friction between the walls of the can and its content means that the content will not (or only barely) rotate. An empty can and one **of the same total mass** ...

Comment: ... but filled with gas/inviscid liquid will finish the race at the same time.

Comment: @Gert Thanks for your comment. I'm looking for a substance for which this idea of rolling cylinders down an incline and seeing which one is faster could determine whether this substance is present in the cylinder or not. This, therefore, also must be a substance that is light enough such that, when two containers of this substance are held in both of your hands (one filled and one empty), the difference in contents cannot be recognized, leading to this experiment. Gases, as you say, would not produce a noticeable difference. Do you know of any other substance that, in reality, might?

Comment: Think Gallium, with an MP of only 30 C it's easy to create two 'identical' cylinders. One with solid Ga, one with liquid Ga.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for pointing that out. Additionally, do you know of any real life (whether daily basis or in industry) applications of this phenomena?

Comment: In other words, how could one benefit from knowing the relationship between hollowness and time taken to roll down an incline?

Comment: I can't see any applications because the comparison is only valid at equal mass and radius, that's not so easy to engineer.

Comment: How is the comparison only valid at equal mass and radius? Cylinders with different masses and radii but fully solid take the same time to roll down an incline, whilst hollow cylinders take more time than solid ones - isn't that correct?

Comment: For example: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222530/rotation-of-fluid-filled-cylinders?rq=1

Comment: If two cylinders are released from the same height, with different masses and different radii, but both solid, they will both reach the bottom of the incline at the same time. That is an established fact, no? I learnt that from Walter Lewin's lecture on moment of inertia.

Comment: So comparison won't be "only valid at equal mass and radius," correct?

Comment: Watch the following from 4:53 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cB8GNQuyMPc

Comment: Sorry. Yes, the mass plays no part, my bad. It's what my own derivation shows too. It is only the inertial moment $I$ that determines velocity and that means that hollow cylinders (or balls) run slower than solid ones. Hollow ones filled with *inviscid* fluid act as hollow ones because the fluid doesn't rotate.

Comment: Ah, I see. I want to thank you for your time. If you do come up with applications of this phenomena (whether pretty trivial in ones daily life or practical used in industry) please do let me know.

Comment: Here's a fun experiment to do. Take two clear, identical pop bottles. Fill both with equal amounts of water and freeze one. To the other, just prior to the 'race' add a drop of food dye without actually mixing it in. Now let them roll down an incline. Observe and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes".

As you say, "we know that hollow cylinders are slower than solid cylinders when rolled down an inclined plane".  That is, a solid cylinder will roll down the ramp faster than a hollow steel cylinder of the same diameter (assuming it is rolling smoothly rather than tumbling end-over-end), because moment of inertia depends on the distribution of mass, with mass further from the axis of rotation contributing more to moment of inertia than mass closer to the axis.

But that's only part of what's in play here.  Here we have the can, which is rolling, and the fluid, which is basically just falling.  The assumption I'm making is that the fluid has a viscosity close to that of water, since the deodorant is mostly water, and by simply shaking a can of it we can tell it's not terribly viscous - it shakes like water in a can.

I just did an experiment, rolling two identical transparent bottles, one empty, the other about half full, down about a 15-degree ramp.  The empty bottle behaved as you would expect an empty cylinder to, rolling slower than the full bottle.  What was also clear is that for a low-viscosity fluid like water, there wasn't enough friction for the water to "spin up" within the bottle - it all stayed on the bottom half of the bottle throughout the journey, so the water added nothing to the moment of inertia about the bottle's axis.  However, being much more massive than the bottle, the water contributed much more to the acceleration than did the bottle itself.  Also, friction between the water and the bottle wasn't enough to make much difference.  Had the liquid been much thicker, the result would be much different, but in this case, the difference in speed between the two bottles was obvious.

For the latter part of your question, the inclined plane is what forces the can to rotate - if you just dropped them, moments of inertia wouldn't factor in at all, and the full and empty cans would drop at very close to the same rate.  The shallower the ramp is, the more the can has to rotate for a given drop in height, and so the more clear the difference is between a can whose motion is dominated by angular momentum (empty can) versus another whose motion is dominated by linear momentum (full can).

Comment: Because the difference in times to reach the bottom of the incline for water was not very different, would you say that the difference for two regular deodorant cans would be negligible (in reality) due to the significantly lower viscosity?

Comment: It WAS very different.  Sorry - I just edited that and added the third paragraph.  However, since the difference between the speeds of the two cans is due mainly to the mass of the fluid NOT contributing to the moment of inertia, it would be just as effective and a lot simpler to simply weigh the cans.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm looking for a substance for which this idea of rolling cylinders down an incline and seeing which one is faster could determine whether this substance is present in the cylinder or not. This, therefore, also must be a substance that is light enough such that, when two containers of this substance are held in both of your hands (one filled and one empty), the difference in contents cannot be recognized, leading to this experiment. Gases, as you say, would not produce a noticeable difference. Do you know of any other substance that, in reality, might?

Comment: I'm trying to find a real life application of this phenomena.

Comment: You could fit a cylinder with  thin ball bearings and a massive central shaft.   Then, if you added a substance (glue) that kept the bearings frozen, the cylinder would act like a solid.   If you didn't put glue in, the bearings would allow the cylinder to reach the bottom of the ramp while the center shaft was still.   That nonrotation of the bearings should mean that there would be substantially slower descent on the ramp.

Comment: @Whit3rd What do you mean by ball bearings and a central shaft?

Comment: @StopReading: he means that the central massive shaft would be like the deodorant.  The point is that if the central mass is allowed to fall freely without being constrained to rotating with the outer cylinder, the cylinder would roll faster.  It's a more sophisticated version of my water-in-a-bottle.  Another version would be to fill two bottles nearly full, freeze one of them, and then compare.  This way, there's no question of whether the total mass having an effect on the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on a couple different things, If the deodorant is a gas or if it is solid, what you mean by noticeable and what type of friction there is. 
For the first part if you are comparing a solid deodorant than the solid deodorant can will always be sqrt(3)/2 faster than the empty can (a simple conservation of energy problem).

If it is a gas than it gets more complicated. The effect will be much less noticeable as it is will be harder to create rotation among the gas to the point if you consider the gas to be an ideal gas then there will be almost no difference.

To make this effect more noticeable is to increase the height that the cans are released from. This means either increasing the length of the ramp or increasing the angle. Mass and radius of the cylinders should not matter.

If the amount of friction is only enough to cause the cylinders to roll without slipping then all I said above is true but if you have less friction then the cylinders will just slid down the ramp and have the same speed. If you have more friction then you will have a much more complicated problem.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question very well. It's more a comment than an actual answer.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is called [mass moment of inertia](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mi.html). For the general case of cylinder with an inner and outer wall the formula is

$$ I_{\rm cyl} = \frac{m}{2} \left( r_O^2 + r_I^2 \right) $$

The two extreme cases are:

1. Solid cylinder - $r_O = R$, $r_I = 0$ $$I_{\rm cyl} = \frac{m}{2} R^2$$
2. Hollow cylinder - $r_O = R$, $r_I=R$ $$I_{\rm cyl} = \frac{m}{2} 2 R^2 = m R^2$$

Now take a hollow cylinder and add a gas (no liquid) inside that rotates with the cylinder (steady state solution) then the gas will *add* to the mass moment of inertia and it will slow down the cylinder (accelerate less) under the same conditions.

The total MMOI is:

$$I_{\rm total} = I_{\rm cyl} + I_{\rm gas} = m_{\rm cyl} R^2 + \frac{m_{\rm gas}}{2} R^2 $$

So in theory yes, but in reality since $m_{\rm gas} \ll m_{\rm cyl}$ you won't notice a difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm looking for a substance for which this idea of rolling cylinders down an incline and seeing which one is faster could determine whether this substance is present in the cylinder or not. This, therefore, also must be a substance that is light enough such that, when two containers of this substance are held in both of your hands (one filled and one empty), the difference in contents cannot be recognized, leading to this experiment. Gases, as you say, would not produce a noticeable difference. Do you know of any other substance that, in reality, might?

Comment: It is a matter of relative density I suppose.